# What is the use of Composite key in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have three tables,

1. master table
2. transaction table
3. master_transaction_link table

here my question is, in link table, which has id,mstrid,transid - mstrid is id of mster table and transid is id of transction table

why should i set the mstrid and transid as composite key in link table.?

what is the use of composite key in link table?

Comment: A composite key consists of more than one attribute to uniquely identify an entity occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Composite key can be considered as a logical join of these two tables and you can save a column from link table if you use logical columns.

If you consider using somekind of ORM in your software i would suggess to use surrogate as primary key, even thought that many ORM's supports composite keys, but they are sometimes harder to handle.

Also data storing is cheap nowadays and saving a one column isnt usually worth it.